# Is the hairy skin below a chestnut’s tough skin poisonous?

Tags: nuts, skin, chestnuts

Disclaimer: As I live in a tropical country, I have never seen chestnuts before.

I was experimenting with chestnuts, after i roasted and peeled them, I read that you’re not supposed to eat the hairy skin of the chestnut. Is it poisonous?

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons [chestnuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castanea_sativa) are usually eaten fully peeled:

1. The thin fuzzy membrane can be bitter, especially in raw nuts. Cooking and roasting mellows it a bit.
2. The membrane is hard, fibrous and unpleasant, especially compared with the soft interior.

Note that the skin is not poisonous, but depending on the intended use<sup>1</sup> of the chestnuts, it’s probably a good idea to really take the time to clean the nuts properly. If prepared right and still hot, the skin should come off easily.

---

<sup>1</sup> Think purée, desserts or [marrons glacés](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marron_glac%C3%A9). If I buy roasted chestnuts on the street, I just peel as good as I can and don’t bother with tiny pieces of skin.